# Parse XML - Retrieve the Portion Between the Double Quotes

Tags: sql-server, xml-parsing, xquery-sql

I have the following XML that is in an XML column in SQL Server. I am able to retrieve the data between the tags  and list it in table format using the code at the bottom.  I can retrieve the values between all the tags except for the one I have in bold below that is in double quotes. I can get the value X just fine but I need to get the 6 that is in between the double quotes in this part: `<Organization501cInd organization501cTypeTxt="6">X</Organization501cInd>`

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://www.irs.gov/efile')
SELECT ID, FilingYear, FilingPeriod, FilingType, [FileName]

, Organization501c3Ind = c.value('(//Organization501c3Ind/text())[1]','varchar(MAX)')
, Organization501cInd = c.value('(//Organization501cInd/text())[1]','varchar(MAX)')
, Organization501cTypeTxt = c.value('(//Organization501cTypeTxt/text())[1]','varchar(MAX)')


FROM Form990
    CROSS APPLY XMLData.nodes('//Return') AS t(c)
    CROSS APPLY XMLData.nodes('//Return/ReturnHeader/Filer') AS t2(c2)
```

XML:

```
<ReturnData documentCnt="2">
    <IRS990 documentId="IRS990-01" referenceDocumentId="IRS990ScheduleO-01" referenceDocumentName="IRS990ScheduleO ReasonableCauseExplanation" softwareId="19009670">
      <PrincipalOfficerNm>CAREY BAKER</PrincipalOfficerNm>
      <USAddress>
        <AddressLine1Txt>PO BOX 11275</AddressLine1Txt>
        <CityNm>TALLAHASSEE</CityNm>
        <StateAbbreviationCd>FL</StateAbbreviationCd>
        <ZIPCd>32302</ZIPCd>
      </USAddress>
      <GrossReceiptsAmt>104241</GrossReceiptsAmt>
      <GroupReturnForAffiliatesInd>false</GroupReturnForAffiliatesInd>
      <Organization501cInd organization501cTypeTxt="6">X</Organization501cInd>
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Aside... stop using `//` everywhere. It's causes a lot of unnecessary XMLDOM traversal.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Your XML sample is not well-formed XML. Additionally, it doesn't contain any namespaces that are used in T-SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a minimal reproducible example by the OP, shooting from the hip.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @Form990 TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, XMLData XML);
INSERT INTO @Form990(XMLData) VALUES
(N'<Return xmlns="http://www.irs.gov/efile" returnVersion="2019v5.1">
    <ReturnData documentCnt="2">
        <IRS990 documentId="IRS990-01" referenceDocumentId="IRS990ScheduleO-01" referenceDocumentName="IRS990ScheduleO ReasonableCauseExplanation" softwareId="19009670">
            <PrincipalOfficerNm>CAREY BAKER</PrincipalOfficerNm>
            <USAddress>
                <AddressLine1Txt>PO BOX 11275</AddressLine1Txt>
                <CityNm>TALLAHASSEE</CityNm>
                <StateAbbreviationCd>FL</StateAbbreviationCd>
                <ZIPCd>32302</ZIPCd>
            </USAddress>
            <GrossReceiptsAmt>104241</GrossReceiptsAmt>
            <GroupReturnForAffiliatesInd>false</GroupReturnForAffiliatesInd>
            <Organization501c3Ind>X</Organization501c3Ind>
            <Organization501cInd organization501cTypeTxt="6">X</Organization501cInd>
        </IRS990>
    </ReturnData>
</Return>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://www.irs.gov/efile')
SELECT -- ID, FilingYear, FilingPeriod, FilingType, [FileName]
    Organization501c3Ind = c.value('(Organization501c3Ind/text())[1]','varchar(MAX)')
    , Organization501cInd = c.value('(Organization501cInd/text())[1]','varchar(MAX)')
    , Organization501cTypeTxt = c.value('(Organization501cInd/@organization501cTypeTxt)[1]','varchar(MAX)')
FROM @Form990
    CROSS APPLY XMLData.nodes('/Return/ReturnData/IRS990') AS t(c)
```

**Output**

```
+----------------------+---------------------+-------------------------+
| Organization501c3Ind | Organization501cInd | Organization501cTypeTxt |
+----------------------+---------------------+-------------------------+
| X                    | X                   |                       6 |
+----------------------+---------------------+-------------------------+
```

Comment: This was perfect!!!

Comment: The answer is following the same **minimal reproducible example** pattern. You copy it to SSMS as-is, and it is working right away. And anybody can repeat, and learn from it.

Answer (score 0):

> NOTE: XML element and attribute names are case-sensitive. i.e.: `Organization501cTypeTxt` will not match an attribute named `organization501cTypeTxt`.

When extracting attributes you need to use the `@` accessor in your XPath query. Try something like the following...

```sql
WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://www.irs.gov/efile')
SELECT  ID, FilingYear, FilingPeriod, FilingType, [FileName],
    Organization501cInd = c2.value('(Organization501cInd/text())[1]','varchar(MAX)'),
    organization501cTypeTxt = c2.value('(Organization501cInd/@organization501cTypeTxt)[1]','varchar(MAX)')
FROM Form990
    CROSS APPLY XMLData.nodes('/ReturnData') AS t(c)
    CROSS APPLY t.c.nodes('IRS990') AS t2(c2);
```

Comment: Thank you!!! This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, how can I run and test your answer's T-SQL without a matching XML?

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky same way you'd test the OPs query without any table DDL or sample data.